# Почему функция shuffle не работает внутри addEventListener?

Tags: javascript, разработка-игр

Игра в пятнашки на js. При клике на кнопку shuffle ничего не происходит. Однако если внутри addEventListener вызвать функцию, с помощью которой создается игральная доска, shuffle начинает работать, но получается так, что доска прописывается дважды и накладывается одна на другую. Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это исправить.

```
let newPos;
function shuffle(cubesReverse) {
  for (let i = cubesReverse.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
    newPos = Math.floor(Math.random() * (i + 1));  
    [cubesReverse[i], cubesReverse[newPos]] = [
      cubesReverse[newPos],
      cubesReverse[i],
    ];
  }
}

const shuffleButton = document.createElement("button");
shuffleButton.setAttribute("id", "button");
shuffleButton.classList.add("shuffleButton");
shuffleButton.textContent = "SHUFFLE";
root.append(shuffleButton);

shuffleButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  shuffle(cubesReverse);
});

function setPosition(){
  for (let i = 1; i <= 15; i++) {
  cube = document.createElement("div");
  
  cube.classList.add("cube");
  cube.textContent = cubesReverse[i - 1] + 1;
  right = i % rowColumnLength;
  bottom = (i - right) / rowColumnLength;

    cube.style.bottom = setElementStyle(cubeSize, bottom);
    cube.style.right = setElementStyle(cubeSize, right);

    cubes.push({
      bottom: bottom,
      right: right,
      element: cube,
    });

    root.append(cube);
    playing = true;

    cube.addEventListener("click", () => {
      changePosition(i);
      console.log(i);
    });
  }
}

setPosition();
```

Comment: На stackoverflow __на русском__ вопросы задают на русском языке)

Comment: Для начала попробуйте поменять местами `root.append(shuffleButton);` и `shuffleButton.addEventListener` . Кнопка должна начать реагировать на клик. По поводу двойной отрисовки, если она выполняется в функции setPosition, то ищите, где вы ее второй раз вызываете. в приведенном примере она вызывается 1 раз и никак не связана с функцией shuffle, даже переменные не пересекаются

Comment: Спасибо за совет! Я пыталась сделать вот так: shuffleButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
setPosition(); 
shuffle(cubesReverse);
});  и у меня получилось дублирование и наложение игрового поля. А если я уберу отсюда setPosition(), то массив все же перемешивается, я выводила его в консоль, но при этом игровое поле остается на месте.

Answer (score 1):

Update для тех, кто столкнулся с той же проблемой. Сделала функцию reset, положила ее внутрь функции shuffle, а потом вызвала в ней же функцию по отрисовке кубиков, и все получилось.

```
  [...root.children].forEach(el => {
    root.removeChild(el);
  })
  cubes.splice(1)
  blankSpace.bottom = 0;
  blankSpace.right = 0;
};`
```